# Questions relating to cables to use 2013 iMac as external monitor to a 2020 27inch imac?

Tags: display, imac, thunderbolt, thunderbolt-display

wondering if you can use a late 2013 iMac as an external monitor to a 2020 27inch iMac.i spoke to the office supplies tech guy who recommended a thunder port 2 cable but that fits in the 2013 not the 2020 which is a thunderbolt 3! Can this be done? I know there seems to be all sorts of caveats for different models. What I think I need is a cable with a thunderbolt 3 on one end and a thunderbolt 2 in the other but as they don’t seem to exist...any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Since I am using a iMac (21.5 inch, Late 2013) in Target Display Mode, I can state this works with macOS Catalina version 10.15.7 for video but not for sound. If you also need sound, then install High Sierra.

Answer (score 0):

Apple sells a [Thunderbolt 2 to Thunderbolt 3 Adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MMEL2AM/A/thunderbolt-3-usb-c-to-thunderbolt-2-adapter).

Then you only need a Thunderbolt 2 male to male cable to connect it and a keyboard to boot the iMac into target display mode.

Other adapters might also work, but the Apple one is pretty much guaranteed to work.